# If online company wants to deposits money into my banking account and wants me to send it to back to there vendor is it a scam can i be responsible

Tags: scams, online-banking, deposits

Do business do interview on hangout, and then they want to send you money for software but needs all your online banking information? They sent me money through my cash app. They want me send it to there vendor for software. Is that a scam

Comment: Definitely scam.  Real companies don't ask you to buy software - they buy the software and give you a license to access it.  In general, you should be wary of any deal that involves you receiving money (by any method) and forwarding some it elsewhere.  Those are almost always scams, because if this person can send *you* money, there's no legit reason they can't send money to the other place themselves. They're either going to reverse the payment to you (leaving you out whatever money you sent along) or they're covering their tracks for illegal funds by creating a paper trail that leads to you.

Answer (score 5):

It is a scam. Most likely, the vendor is also the scammer and the payment will eventually be reversed. *Never* accept money that you have not earned and is not yours to keep to do with as you like.

Now that you know this company is trying to scam you, I strongly urge you to cut off all contact.